# How to have current file in git but not history of file?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project and am using git and GitHub as my repository (it is a book actually, but the question will be pertinent to code, as well).  Typically, as in software projects, I only keep the source and every time I build the output (the book PDF) from that source.  But since I'm collaborating with someone on this who will not build the output, just look at the current progress, I need to periodically check in the PDF that is generated - but it's large.

I don't actually need the history of the PDF (the output), I just need the latest version in git.  Is there any way to do this?  In other words, I don't want to track the history, just have the tip of any branch have the actual file.

In researching this, I'm thinking that the only way to do this is to periodically purge the history of the file from git and then check in the new PDF.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: No, you don't need to have the pdf committed.  Indeed, you shouldn't.  If your collaborator doesn't want to build the file, make it available through a channel other than git.

Comment: The easiest channel is github, if it supported what I needed, and since github is mostly a host service for git, I was hoping that this was possible.  I could constantly "release" it, but that is too much trouble.  I'll find another way.

Comment: @PeteP, "GitHub" doesn't necessarily mean "Git". You can [create a release](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases) in GitHub. This will cause a Git tag to be created identifying the source version associated with the release, and you can manually upload files (like a PDF) to go with the release (see step 7). IMO this is closest to my answer and I'd be happy to update it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *good* way to do this.  Don't do it.  Do [something else - see Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55681886/1256452).

#### If you insist on doing it anyway

There are several *bad* ways to do this.  Probably the simplest is to create an orphan branch that has no files in it, commit the PDF as a single file in that branch (so that checking out that branch gets you a work-tree with only the one PDF file in it, which you must then *copy somewhere else* and then `git checkout` the branch you really want, which will immediately *remove* the PDF file from your work-tree):

```
$ git status
```

Make sure you have nothing to commit and your work-tree is clean, because you're about to destroy them temporarily.  Then:

```
$ cp built.pdf /tmp/built.pdf          # save the PDF somewhere
$ git checkout --orphan pdfbranch      # create branch for one commit holding PDF
$ git read-tree --empty -u             # clear index and work-tree
$ cp /tmp/built.pdf built.pdf          # restore PDF to work-tree
$ git add built.pdf                    # copy to otherwise-empty index
$ git commit -m 'create built pdf'     # make one commit on branch
$ git checkout master                  # or whatever - PDF file goes away again
```

You can now *delete* the branch `pdfbranch` (from all clones of this Git repository) at any time in the future, so as not to retain the old built PDF file any more, then create a new `pdfbranch` to hold the one built file again.

(You can simplify the above using `git worktree add`, if your Git is at least 2.5: use `git worktree add --detach ../pdf-worktree master` to create a place in which to do the `git checkout --orphan` and `git read-tree --empty -u` steps, after which you can leave the added worktree around as a place to do the next update.  But in general this is all a bad idea.)

You can use a tag instead of a branch name; the effect is the same.  However, tag names are not expected to move, so this method is trickier.

The general idea here, and the reason that this is a bad idea, is that history *is* commits; commits *are* the history in a repository.  To have a file that has no other history, that file must be in exactly one commit.

One other method is to `git add` the pdf as a lone blob object, then attach a *tag* (lightweight or annotated) to the blob object.  Remove the tag to release the object (it will eventually be deleted).  This has the same disadvantages as before, plus the problem of tags not being expected to move, plus the fact that to extract the file, you need to be a bit of a Git guru.

Answer (score 4):

You're in core command territory here. You don't want history, you just want content, so use its content-tracker core.  The only question is, how much do you want Git to do for you?

The simplest procedurally is to simply tag the blob:

```
$ make book.pdf
$ git tag -f current-book `git hash-object -w book.pdf`
```

And you're done.  Few if any of the source-control commands will have any idea what to do with that tag, it's not even a tree, just a blob, but Git's core commands will work just fine.

```
$ git fetch origin current-book
$ git show FETCH_HEAD >book.pdf
$ open book.pdf
```

Comment: I like this answer. It tells OP how to do what they asked for, and it does it with standard tools. But I'd like it more if it mentioned why doing this in the repo might not be desirable and touched on the "tags aren't expected to move" point that torek made.

Comment: I'm getting the "don't do it" and from the complexity of the answers, I can see that git really isn't designed to do this.  If I do what jthill suggests, will I see the book.pdf on the master branch?  No, I think, which would make this whole exercise pointless, because the collaborator is not a git expert - she'd need to be one just to get the file.  So I think I'll find another way.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't include it in the repository at all. Instead, I would treat this like a build artifact. You could even generate it using a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool every time you push to GitHub.

For example, using Travis CI you could build your PDF and have it [uploaded as a GitHub release](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/)  whenever you tag a new version. You can also configure CI jobs to run when you push (or merge) code to a particular branch.

Other major continuous integration tools will be able to do this kind of thing too, so I encourage you to shop around and find the one that fits your needs best.